# My PostgreSQL 10 query is very slow, need a way to make it faster

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, prisma

**I'm using PostgreSQL 10**

Here is my model:
https://imgur.com/bibWSq8

Each `review` belongs to only one `product`. Each `product` can belong to many `category`s. Each `category` can have only one parent `category`.
I'm using Prisma to query the database. It's a kind of ORM.
I want to select the first 10 `review`s of all `product`s that belong to the `category` which has `id = 27`.

Here is the query that is generated by Prisma:

```
select
"Alias"."id"
from "database"."review" as "Alias"
where ("Alias"."id"
       in (select "database"."review"."id"
           from "database"."review"
           where "database"."review"."product"
                 in (select "database"."category_to_product"."product"
                     from "database"."category_to_product"
                     join "database"."category" as "category_product_Alias"
                        on "category_product_Alias"."id" = "database"."category_to_product"."category"
                     where ("category_product_Alias"."id" = 27
                            or "category_product_Alias"."id"
                               in (select "database"."category"."id"
                                   from "database"."category"
                                   join "database"."category" as "category_category_product_Alias"
                                      on "category_category_product_Alias"."id" = "database"."category"."parent"
                                   where "category_category_product_Alias"."id" = 27
                                  )
                           )
                    )
          )
      )
order by "Alias"."id" desc
limit 11
offset 0;
```

There are 1.500.000 `review`s, 12.000 `product`s and 130 `category`s. That query take almost 3s to complete.

I tried to create indexes but it didn't work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX category_pkey ON "database".category USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX idx_category_parent ON "database".category USING btree (parent)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "category_to_product_AB_unique" ON "database".category_to_product USING btree (category, product)
CREATE INDEX "category_to_product_B" ON "database".category_to_product USING btree (product))
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_pkey ON "database".product USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX idx_review_product ON "database".review USING btree (product)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX review_pkey ON "database".review USING btree (id)
```

And here is the result when running `explain analyze`:

```
Limit  (cost=9.00..101.89 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=3428.508..3431.048 rows=11 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=9.00..12584725.82 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=3428.507..3431.043 rows=11 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: ("Alias".id = review.id)
        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using review_pkey on review "Alias"  (cost=0.43..84869.82 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=0.008..152.954 rows=1054436 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=8.57..12477502.61 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=3188.974..3191.303 rows=11 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using review_pkey on review  (cost=0.43..266561.32 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=0.004..415.244 rows=1054436 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.14..8.18 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1054436)
                    ->  Index Scan using "category_to_product_B" on category_to_product  (cost=0.29..0.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1054436)
                          Index Cond: (product = review.product)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using category_pkey on category "category_product_Alias"  (cost=7.86..7.88 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1084175)
                          Index Cond: (id = category_to_product.category)
                          Filter: ((id = 27) OR (hashed SubPlan 1))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                          Heap Fetches: 0
                          SubPlan 1
                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..7.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
                                  ->  Seq Scan on category  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
                                        Filter: (parent = 27)
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 148
                                  ->  Seq Scan on category "category_category_product_Alias"  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                                        Filter: (id = 27)
Planning time: 0.649 ms
Execution time: 3431.098 ms
```

I think my data is not too large, but the query is too slow. Is there any way to make it faster?

**Update 1**
I just do @Laurenz Albe 's way, it's faster. Here is the result

```
Limit  (cost=217773.56..217773.59 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=735.033..735.041 rows=11 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=217773.56..221499.13 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=735.031..735.033 rows=11 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (("Alias".id + 0)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=99929.33..184545.76 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=354.030..733.405 rows=13589 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ("Alias".id = review.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on review "Alias"  (cost=0.00..60400.26 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=0.005..157.747 rows=1482065 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=81301.50..81301.50 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=350.842..350.842 rows=13589 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2097152  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16862kB
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=410.63..81301.50 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=3.363..347.392 rows=13589 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (review.product = category_to_product.product)
                          ->  Seq Scan on review  (cost=0.00..60400.26 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=0.011..144.852 rows=1482065 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=326.86..326.86 rows=6702 width=4) (actual time=2.121..2.121 rows=100 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 68kB
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=259.84..326.86 rows=6702 width=4) (actual time=2.064..2.103 rows=100 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: category_to_product.product
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=12.86..243.08 rows=6702 width=4) (actual time=0.336..2.026 rows=100 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (category_to_product.category = "category_product_Alias".id)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on category_to_product  (cost=0.00..194.03 rows=13403 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.873 rows=12063 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=11.93..11.93 rows=74 width=4) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on category "category_product_Alias"  (cost=7.71..11.93 rows=74 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        Filter: ((id = 27) OR (hashed SubPlan 1))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 147
                                                        SubPlan 1
                                                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..7.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                ->  Seq Scan on category  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                                      Filter: (parent = 27)
                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 148
                                                                ->  Seq Scan on category "category_category_product_Alias"  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                                                                      Filter: (id = 27)
Planning time: 0.591 ms
Execution time: 735.127 ms
```

**Update 2**
I tried to simplify the query:

```
explain analyze select
"review"."id"
from "review"
where "review"."product" in
(
select "category_to_product"."product"
from "category_to_product"
join "category"
on "category"."id" = "category_to_product"."category"
where "category"."id" = 27 or "category"."parent" = 27
)
order by "reviewty$dev"."review"."id" desc
limit 11
offset 0;
```

But the result doesn't change too much

```
Limit  (cost=0.86..456.52 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=3354.756..3357.181 rows=11 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.86..1019733.07 rows=24617 width=4) (actual time=3354.754..3357.176 rows=11 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using review_pkey on review  (cost=0.43..266561.32 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=0.007..391.076 rows=1054436 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..0.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1054436)
              ->  Index Scan using "category_to_product_B" on category_to_product  (cost=0.29..0.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1054436)
                    Index Cond: (product = review.product)
              ->  Index Scan using category_pkey on category  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1084175)
                    Index Cond: (id = category_to_product.category)
                    Filter: ((id = 27) OR (parent = 27))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning time: 0.434 ms
Execution time: 3357.210 ms
```

The only way I can do now is appending `+ 0` after `order by "Alias"."id"`. So sad, as I said, this query is generated by Prisma (prisma.io), not by me, I want to to write native sql.

**Update 3**
@Ancoron is right, `set enable_nestloop = off` before running my query will make it faster. It forces PostgreSQL to use `hash join` instead of `nested loop`.

```
Limit  (cost=10000238022.63..10000238023.45 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=629.606..629.804 rows=11 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=10000238022.63..10000348970.97 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=629.605..629.797 rows=11 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: ("Alias".id = review.id)
        ->  Index Only Scan Backward using review_pkey on review "Alias"  (cost=0.43..84869.82 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=0.006..152.252 rows=1054436 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Sort  (cost=10000238022.20..10000241747.77 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=390.996..391.000 rows=11 loops=1)
              Sort Key: review.id DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1021kB
              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=10000000604.70..10000085221.14 rows=1490226 width=4) (actual time=4.306..388.164 rows=13589 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (review.product = category_to_product.product)
                    ->  Seq Scan on review  (cost=0.00..60400.26 rows=1490226 width=8) (actual time=0.004..157.976 rows=1482065 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=10000000529.30..10000000529.30 rows=6032 width=4) (actual time=0.617..0.617 rows=100 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 68kB
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=10000000008.29..10000000529.30 rows=6032 width=4) (actual time=0.555..0.603 rows=100 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (category_to_product.category = "category_product_Alias".id)
                                ->  Index Only Scan using "category_to_product_AB_unique" on category_to_product  (cost=0.29..419.82 rows=12063 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.374 rows=2272 loops=1)
                                      Heap Fetches: 1123
                                ->  Index Only Scan using category_pkey on category "category_product_Alias"  (cost=10000000007.86..10000000018.82 rows=74 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((id = 27) OR (hashed SubPlan 1))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 147
                                      Heap Fetches: 0
                                      SubPlan 1
                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000007.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                                              ->  Seq Scan on category  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                    Filter: (parent = 27)
                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 148
                                              ->  Seq Scan on category "category_category_product_Alias"  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                                                    Filter: (id = 27)
Planning time: 0.594 ms
Execution time: 629.857 ms
```

But I ask myself, why I have to do this, PostgreSQL picks the wrong plan, it uses nested loop instead of hash join, it makes my query slower. It's mature database, so I believed that was my fault when the query is slow, I tried to create indexes, rewrite the query in the hope that PostgreSQL would change its plan, but it didn't. Is it acceptable? Another thing, I'm sure my query will run faster in every case.
Here is my Prisma query:

```
# Write your query or mutation here
query {
  reviews (where: {
    product:{
      categories_some: {
        OR:[
          {
            id: 27
          },
          {
            parent: {
              id: 27
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }, orderBy:id_DESC, first:11, skip:0){
    id
  }
}
```

I don't find another way to change my Prisma query.

Comment: Considering the deep nested logic, maybe it is the execution plan construction that's slow? If so, then a prepared statement will be an improvement.

Comment: I think the query can be simplified to this: http://dpaste.com/1PV1NYM I am not 100% if it is the same, but I can't setup all  the tables and test data and you didn't provide any in your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank for you comment but your query is very very slow. Here is the result of it: http://dpaste.com/3JWXQX4

Comment: Strange. This is how I tested it: http://dpaste.com/1383N83 - but with that setup your query is also very fast [11 milliseconds](https://explain.depesz.com/s/nQPx) vs. [2 milliseconds](https://explain.depesz.com/s/78S)  (my first query wasn't correct, but don't expect that to cause the difference)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just run your query again. it's slow as my query.
http://dpaste.com/222FF2W

Comment: If you switch the columns for the index `category_to_product_AB_unique` to `(product, category)` you should get the same performance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hum, I swap two columns but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that due to an adversary distribution of the rows in the tables, the interesting rows come up last when PostgreSQL tries to use index scans to get the correct order.

Try to avoid index scans and use an explicit sort by changing the `ORDER BY` clause to

```
ORDER BY "Alias".id + 0 DESC
```

What do I mean by “adversary distribution”? Based on its estimates, PostgreSQL thinks that there are quite a lot of rows that satisfy the condition, so it thinks that it is cheapest if it processes the rows in descending `Alias.id` order and just keeps going until it has found 11 rows satisfying the condition. Even if the guess is right, it may be that the (many) rows that satisfy the condition all have low `Alias.id`, so it has to compute way more rows than it bargained for.

Seeing your second execution plan, I suspect that at least part of the problem is that PostgreSQL over-estimates the number of rows that satisfy the condition: 1490226 instead of 13589 rows. Simplifying the query might help.

Comment: Do you have a reference why the `<order-column> + 0` should make a difference?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I just update the result, my query is faster. Do you have any reference about `adversary distribution of the rows`? The bad thing is I can't change my query because it's generated by Prisma (an ORM library). I have to write native sql, I think so. Do you have any other ways?

Comment: @Ancoron Read `match_clause_to_ordering_op` in `src/backend/optimizer/path/indxpath.c`.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thank for your explanation. It's so clear now.

Comment: I just update the result after simplifying the query, it doesn't change too much :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the nested loop joins using `SET enable_nestloop = off` before running the query (IDK if that's possible to include with prisma).

That gives me an even slightly better execution time as with `ORDER BY ... + 0 DESC` without modifying the query at all: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Mi4W

I've created a full online example with slightly reduced data set (but still takes a while to load) to test the different queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2c4d104804f57e1a59f7ed31bd57e2f5

If you're working with prisma, it probably would also be a good idea to share your prisma request from the client that's resulting into this SQL query. Maybe something can be done on that side as well.

From the query perspective, probably an optimization fence using a CTE gives the best possible result:

```sql
WITH
    cte_reviews (id) AS (
        SELECT r.id
        FROM review AS r
            INNER JOIN category_to_product AS cp ON (r.product = cp.product)
        WHERE
            cp.category IN (
                SELECT 27
                UNION ALL
                SELECT id FROM category WHERE parent = 27
            )
        ORDER BY 1 ASC
    )
SELECT id
FROM cte_reviews
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0;
```

So here, we're enforcing a forward index (only) scan and then just reverse and limit the result of that, which is much faster in this special case.

Down to ~22 milliseconds:

```
Planning time: 0.577 ms
Execution time: 22.021 ms
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate what you did. You can check Update 3.

Comment: Found another even faster query variant: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b67d975f05e75566a69450f81f2e4710 However, as prisma.io claims they're generating optimal SQL I would be tempted to file a bug at their side.